# How to change the style of one block in tikzposter package?

Tags: tikzposter

I want to change the style of only one block "Objectives", but at the same time i like theme Desert. I would like this block to have black frame and background color like title of my poster has. Any ideas how to manage it?!

```
\documentclass[25pt, a1papper, portrait]{tikzposter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\title{\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering dsfds sdfsfd}}
\author{fdssfa}
\date{\today}
\institute{fsdfs sdfdsfds}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{comment}
\usetheme{Desert}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\block{Introduction}
{
    \blindtext
}


\begin{columns}
    \column{0.4}
    {

     \colorlet{blocktitlebgcolor}{red}
    \colorlet{blockbodybgcolor}{blue}
     \colorlet{framecolor}{black}
    \useblockstyle{Basic}
    \block{Objectives}{\blindtext \vspace{2cm}

}}

    \column{0.6}{
    \block{Something else}{Here, \blindtext \vspace{4cm}}
    \note[
        targetoffsetx=-9cm,
        targetoffsety=-6.5cm,
        width=0.5\linewidth
        ]
        {e-mail \texttt{sharelatex@sharelatex.com}}}
\end{columns}

\begin{columns}
    \column{0.5}
    \block{A figure}
    {
        \begin{tikzfigure}

        \end{tikzfigure}
    }
    \column{0.5}
    \block{Description of the figure}{\blindtext}
\end{columns}
\block[titleleft,titleoffsetx=2em,titleoffsety=1em,bodyoffsetx=2em,
bodyoffsety=1em,titlewidthscale=.6, bodywidthscale=.8, roundedcorners=14,
linewidth=8mm, bodyinnersep=4em, titleinnersep=2em]
{Sample Block}{Text\\Text\\Text Text}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what you are after as your title does not seem to have a black frame, but perhaps this will get you started. You can define a new block style using `\defineblockstyle`, which allows you to set-up the characteristics of the block as you want them. I have then wrapped this new block inside a `\myblock` command that can be used to create a single bloc in a particular style. By default, it creates block in the "MyBlock" style but it can be used for any style:

```
\myblock{title}{content}%           a block in the "MyBlock" style
\myblock[Envelope]{title}{content}% a block in the "Envelope" style
```

Secondly I have defined the "MyBlock" style to do what I think you want. With this in place your MWE produces:

[image]

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass[25pt, a1papper, portrait]{tikzposter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\title{\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering dsfds sdfsfd}}
\author{fdssfa}
\date{\today}
\institute{fsdfs sdfdsfds}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{comment}
\usetheme{Desert}

\defineblockstyle{MyBlock}{% define a custom style for a block
    titlewidthscale=0.8, bodywidthscale=1, titlecenter,
    titleoffsetx=0pt, titleoffsety=0pt, bodyoffsetx=0pt, bodyoffsety=15mm,
    bodyverticalshift=15mm, roundedcorners=22, linewidth=5pt,
    titleinnersep=8mm, bodyinnersep=8mm
}{
    \draw[rounded corners=\blockroundedcorners, inner sep=\blockbodyinnersep,
          line width=\blocklinewidth, color=black,
          top color=titlebgcolor!90, bottom color=titlebgcolor!20!white,
          %fill=blockbodybgcolor
          ]
      (blockbody.south west) rectangle (blockbody.north east); %
    \ifBlockHasTitle%
        \draw[rounded corners=\blockroundedcorners, inner sep=\blocktitleinnersep,
          top color=titlebgcolor!90, bottom color=titlebgcolor!20!white,
          line width=\blocklinewidth, color=black, %fill=blocktitlebgcolor
          ]
      (blocktitle.south west) rectangle (blocktitle.north east); %
    \fi%
}
\newcommand\myblock[3][MyBlock]{\useblockstyle{#1}\block{#2}{#3}\useblockstyle{Basic}}



\begin{document}
\useblockstyle{Basic}

\maketitle

\block{Introduction}
{
    \blindtext
}


\begin{columns}
    \column{0.4}
    \myblock{Objectives}{% use custom block to define the objectives
      \blindtext \vspace{2cm}
     }

    \column{0.6}{
    \block{Something else}{Here, \blindtext \vspace{4cm}}
    \note[
        targetoffsetx=-9cm,
        targetoffsety=-6.5cm,
        width=0.5\linewidth
        ]
        {e-mail \texttt{sharelatex@sharelatex.com}}}
\end{columns}

\begin{columns}
    \column{0.5}
    \block{A figure}
    {
        \begin{tikzfigure}

        \end{tikzfigure}
    }
    \column{0.5}
    \block{Description of the figure}{\blindtext}
\end{columns}
\block[titleleft,titleoffsetx=2em,titleoffsety=1em,bodyoffsetx=2em,
bodyoffsety=1em,titlewidthscale=.6, bodywidthscale=.8, roundedcorners=14,
linewidth=8mm, bodyinnersep=4em, titleinnersep=2em]
{Sample Block}{Text\\Text\\Text Text}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's almost I wanted except one thing. I would like the style of all future colomns and blocks has the same features as rounded corners, shading and so on. But here "Introduction" and "Something else" have different styles.

Comment: @David This was how you set it up in your question! To fix this all that you need to do is move the `\useblockstyle{Basic}` command up to the top of the document. I have just edited my solution so that it does it this way.